# SQLiteDatabase IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am having trouble querying the my SQLiteDatabase using my custom ContentProvider. I am trying to query the database for one user using the 'user_id'. The following pieces of code which are associated with the problem are:

DBProvider.java

```
@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder){
        int match_code = myUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Cursor c;
        switch (match_code){
            case USER_BY_ID: {
                c = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
                        DBContract.User_Table.TABLE_NAME,
                        projection,
                        DBContract.User_Table.COLUMN_ID + "='" + ContentUris.parseId(uri) + "'",
                        selectionArgs,
                        null,
                        null,
                        sortOrder
                );
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
}
```

ProfileActivity.java

```
// Columns to load
        String[] columns = {
                DBContract.User_Table.COLUMN_NAME // String "name"
        };
// A cursor is your primary interface to the query results.
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(DBContract.User_Table.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(id)), // Table to Query
                columns, // Columns for the WHERE
                DBContract.User_Table.COLUMN_ID, // selection
                new String[]{"1"}, // Values for the WHERE
                null // Sort Args
        );
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(DBContract.User_Table.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(id)), // Table to Query
                columns, // Columns for the WHERE
                DBContract.User_Table.COLUMN_ID, // selection
                null, // Values for the WHERE
                null // Sort Args
        );
```

You are using the `selectionArgs` parameter wrong. You don't have any `?` in the `selection` parameter and the binding fails. More info in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)).

> `selectionArgs` -  You may include ?s in selection, which will be
>   replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in the order that they
>   appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.